# Phone Hotspot Connection Problem

Tags: internet, hot-spot

I turned on the hotspot on my Android phone then I connected the laptop to my phone hotspot. Now the laptop is connected but with a question mark on the wifi icon on the top bar. So it's connected but no internet and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Does your phone have internet access?

Comment: Yes of course. The phone had internet

Comment: If you want to communicate with your phone via Bluetooth, on your computer, go to Settings, Wi-Fi, turn Wi-Fi OFF. Then go to Bluetooth turn it to ON if it is not already, switch your connection to your phone ON. Go to Bluetooth icon in the upper right corner, click on it, then click on connect to internet under the phone you have selected.

Comment: But I want to connect to phone wifi hotspot, not Bluetooth?